# Storing optional data in a separate table or as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `User` table where users can sign in using Google or Facebook. To allow them to sign in again, I would like to save a `social_id` column, one for Google and one for Facebook so the user can login again.

Not every user is going to sign in with their social accounts so there is the traditional email password option.

In terms of performance, storage and scalability, would it be better to:

- Have a `social_id` column in the `User` table which is optional
- Have a new table called `Social` which contains a primary key, two `social_id`'s, one for Facebook and one for Google and a foreign key linking the the primary key in the `User` table.

Thanks.

Comment: Will a given user have exactly zero or one social_id values? Or possibly multiple?

Comment: @OllieJones I forgot to mention that there will be a `social_id` for Facebook and another for Google sign in. So a given user will have Null if there is no social login and obviously the `social_id` if there is.

Comment: @PavSidhu Edit your question. That comment dramatically reduces your options!

Comment: @Strawberry Sure I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your social_id :: user relationship is  0-n :: 1 (many to one). That circumstance demands a separate table (unless you are going to denormalize your other table, which is not a good idea.).

So you need a `social` table with the following columns:

```
user_id      (FK to the Users table)
social_type  (1 = fb, 2 = goog, 3 = linked in etc).
social_id    the id from the network mentioned in social_type
```

The first two columns taken together will be your primary key.  To get the facebook id for a particular user, you'll use this query

```
 SELECT s.social_id
   FROM Users
   LEFT JOIN social ON Users.user_id = social.user_id AND social.social_type=1
  WHERE Users.name = 'zuck'
```

This will kick back NULL if the named user has no appropriate social_id, or the value you need.

I recommend against adding an extra primary key id column to the `social` table, because the combination primary id is more efficient. For example, it lets you change a social value with MySQL's upsert: `INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

I recommend STRONGLY against putting two columns for the two different social networks in each row of the table.  Because, three or more social networks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the second option as pointed below since `user` to `social media` mostly would be a one-many relationship; since one user may have many social media registration like `facebook`/`Google` and may opt to login with different social media authentication.

*Have a new table called Social which contains a primary key, the social_id and a foreign key linking the the primary key in the User table.*

On the other hand if it's restricted for the user to login with only one social media account then having a optional nullable column in your `user` table makes much sense(Which is your first option).